# npm: How can I make my own module's interface/classes exportable in another module?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I am a newbie for `npm`. I created a module with name `"ModuleA"` with several interfaces like `"export interface name"`, and publish this module.

In another Module project, I have `"npm install ModuleA --save "` in the second module. However I don't know how to import the interfaces from ModuleA. I tried either `"import {interfacename} from ModuleA"` or `var myinterface = require(ModuleA)`. Both of them don't work. Could anyone help me?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Is it the compiled JavaScript that you're distributing on NPM?

Comment: oh, I write the interface in the typescript file, so do I need to compile the typescript and generate javascript file?